# Why was voting corrected on my questions?

Tags: support

I posted 3 questions in a series recently, one of which got closed which is not a problem. But suddenly I got a -30 rep change for "[voting corrected](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)".

For two of the questions I got 1 upvote each and I thought "nice, at least no downvotes/close-votes, and even better, someone thought they were worth +1".

Maybe my "series" question caused this since the system regards this as abnormal behavior, since the upvoter voted for them in a short period of time...

Can this (the "questions in series" situation) be regarded as a bug of the voting correction system and be reported to the developers?

Very disappointed by the SE system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug. There was a user who voted on many posts across the Stack Exchange network in order to hunt voting badges. Those votes were invalidated which is why you see the "Voting Corrected" entry in your reputation history.

From [this Main Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362059/321725),

> All of those votes that were determined to be "scripted" for the purpose of obtaining badges were invalidated. They are all marked as invalidated like any other invalidated vote in the system because we do not have any other way of marking a vote as invalidated.

> As far as I know, this is the first time we have ever invalidated votes in such a way. We would normally just delete their profiles to invalidate all the votes, in which case a bunch of users would all see a series of "User was removed" history entries instead. If we choose to continue using this process to invalidate mass voting sprees like this, we will find a way to clarify this possible case in the help center.